# how do i move a wordpress blog to a wordpress site with a blog

Tags: wordpress

Client had a flat file php site and wanted a blog, so I installed wordpress stand along blog. Now they want to convert then entire site to Wordpress. The current blog is in a subdirectory called "blog". I would like to create a blog page called "blog" on the new site and import the posts that are in the WP standalone blog installation.

Can I just take the SQL statements and insert them as autoincrements in the new database. How do I import the tags and categories. What about the author number? It will be painstaking, but I don't want to cut and paste a hundred blog posts.

Comment: They are wanting to move from an installed WordPress instance to a wordpress.com account?

Comment: no it is a regular site with flat files, but it has a WP blog installed in a directory called "blog". Now they want to convert the entire site from flat files over to WP, so now there will be a blog page on the new WP site. I'm trying to figure out how to get the stand alone blog posts into the WP site's blog.

Answer (score 1):

Install WordPress in root http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress .

Create a page called Blog with the slug of /blog/. Set that as your posts page in Dashboard>>Settings>>Reading.

Export your posts,categories, authors and images from the current blog via http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen and then import them http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content into the new WP site. You should be able to keep the same structure to your permalinks.

Then, if needed, create static pages to match the current php pages and cut/paste the content into them.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just make the primary site URL point to the blog site?    Or take a full backup of the blog site and restore it on the main server in doc root?   Then add your pages content right in the current blogging site?   You can point both www.whateversite.com/blog/ to the posts (blog page) or even blog.whateversite.com to the same.

Seems like a LOT of extra work to setup a new WordPress install then go to a current WordPress install and export the blog posts then re-import just the blog posts.

If you absolutely have a great reason for not just using the current WordPress install and building on that then I suggest you spend the $15 and get VaultPress from the Automattic group and backup the blog site.   Then use the restore to alternate URL feature to clone it to a brand new WordPress installation you've started at the new main site.   It will restore the content and replace inline URLs for you which is a HUGE time saver.

I've moved / cloned multiple sites this way.  It is by far the easiest method, especially if your in-blog URLs need to change from blog.blah.com to www.blah.com.